# Ruby on Rails Tutorial Chapter 8 Signup Success

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have written the Users controller and Spec tests correctly for the "successful creation" in the User controller however I get the following two errors:

```
1) UsersController POST 'create' success should create a user
    Failure/Error: lambda do
      count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
    # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:95:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

 2) UsersController POST 'create' success should redirect to the user show page
    Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(user_path(assigns(:user)))
    ActionController::RoutingError:
      No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>#<User id: nil, name: "New User", email: "user@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, encrypted_password: nil, salt: nil>}
    # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:102:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The test specs are as follows:

```
describe "success" do
   before (:each) do
       @attr = { :name => "New User" , 
                  :email => "user@example.com",
                  :password => "foobar",
                  :password_confirmation => "foobar"
                }
   end

   it  "should create a user" do
            lambda do
             post :create, :user => @attr
           end.should change(User, :count).by(1)
        end

   it  "should redirect to the user show page" do
             post :create, :user => @attr
             response.should redirect_to(user_path(assigns(:user)))
        end


   it "should have a welcome message" do
             post :create, :user => @attr
             flash[:success].should =~ /welcome to the sample app/i 
        end

   end 
end
```

The controller code is as follows:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = @user.name
  end

  def new
    @user  = User.new
    @title = "Sign Up"
  end

  def create
     @user = User.new(params[:user])
     if @user.save
       redirect_to @user, :flash => { :success => "Welcome to the Sample App!" }
     else
       @title = "Sign up"
       render 'new'
     end
   end
end
```

I'm also getting one new error:

3) UsersController POST 'create' success should have a welcome message

```
 Failure/Error: flash[:success].should =~ /welcome to the sample app/i
   expected: /welcome to the sample app/i
        got: nil (using =~)
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:107:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here's the user model code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :password

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name, :presence => true, 
                   :length => {:maximum => 50}
  validates :email, :presence => true, 
                    :format => {:with => email_regex}, 
                    :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}
  validates :password, :presence => true,
                       :confirmation => true,
                       :length => {:within => 6..40}

  before_save :encrypt_password

  def has_password?(submitted_password)
    encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
  end

  class << self
    def authenticate(email, submitted_password)
      user = User.find_by_email(email)
      return nil if user.nil?
      return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
    end
  end
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: For the first failure, you need to post both your test spec as well as your controller code, otherwise we can only guess at what is wrong.  For the second failure, you're trying to redirect to a User object that is nil `<User id: nil...` so of course the route can't show a nil object.  You probably forgot to save the User object after building it or you had a validation error with it.

Comment: @iWasRobbed thanks for the input. I have added the test specs and controller code to the original post (there is an additional error now). With regards to the second failure, you can see that the test code creates attributes for a valid user and the controller code saves that User so what's going wrong?

Comment: Chances are, the @user.save method fails. Post your model code as well so we can see the parameters you are providing to the create method are sufficient. Or simply insert some logging statements into the if/else branches to see which one actually gets executed when you run the test.

Comment: @Thilo thanks for the help I have posted the User model code above. I'm not sure if I completely understand what you mean by "insert some logging statements into the if/else branches to see which one actually gets executed when you run the test". Can you elaborate?

Comment: In your create method: Rails.logger.debug("HOORAY") right before the 'redirect'. Rails.logger.debug("OOPS: #{@user.errors.inspect}") right after the following 'else'. Run your test, check out log/test.log and see which branch was taken. If the save fails, you'll know why.

Comment: @Thilo I inserted those logging lines in between my code but nothing comes up in the test.log file. I am using RSpec for testing not the native Rails testing. How can I log the specs?

Comment: Still cannot get the logging statements...help anyone?

Comment: @Thilo I found the logging statements in the server readout and they function appropriately: OOPS:{:name=>["can't be blank"], :email=>["can't be blank", "is invalid"], :password=>["can't be blank", "is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]}

('Successful Save', 'Successful_Save@test.com', '2011-07-19 04:48:41.356491', '2011-07-19 04:48:41.356491', '8270e7c1a8825c233a764defcde1e25e6d1ed0e0da0529ba9d9d2450b9259a3a', '436058647cd4e6ca3a7d255a9b1f897611185527f1e5c342de52b44b61ec79e6')
HOORAY

Comment: It functions correctly in development on local host but when I deploy to remote host (heroku) the sign up does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and for me the problem was the email. I changed it and the tests worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing exactly the same problem and it disappeared strangely. I deleted completely the section it "should have a welcome ..." and copied it again (I would suggest you to copy and paste the following code):

```
  it "should have a welcome message" do
    post :create, :user => @attr
    flash[:success].should =~ /welcome to the sample app/i
  end
```

I know that it has not much sense but it solved my problem and now everything's green.